# Racket Добавление элементов в список

Tags: racket

Здравствуйте учусь racket, делаю калькулятор. На основе идеологии префиксной нотации, интересно насколько это удобно. Делаю функцию памяти и тут затык:
не совсем понимаю почему вот код

```
(define mem null) ; создание переменной памяти с пустым списком
   >mem
   '()
(define (memory x)(append mem (list x))) ; функция заполнения памяти
  >(memory 10)
  '(10)
  >(memory 10)
  '(10)
  >mem
  '()
```

Как видно добавления в переменную коя является списком не происходит видимо я что-то делаю не так

Answer (score 0):

`(append ...)` не меняет исходный список, а возвращает новый, поэтому при вызове `(memory x)` переменная `mem` остается *неизменной*.

Для изменения `mem` вам нужно воспользоваться функцией `(set! id expr)`. Подробнее о ней можно почитать в [документации](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/set_.html#%28form._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._set%21%29%29).

Таким образом, объявление функции `(memory x)` будет выглядеть так:

```
(define (memory x) (set! mem (append mem (list x))))
```

Answer (score 0):

при вызове функции (memory x) список mem не обновляется, поскольку append не изменяет исходный список, а создает новый список с добавленным элементом. Поэтому при повторном вызове функции (memory 10) и выводе значения переменной mem там остается пустой список.

Чтобы решить эту проблему, необходимо изменить функцию memory (x) так, чтобы она возвращала обновленный список, а затем обновляла значение переменной mem на этот список.